# Connect custom rewrite rules and query variables to wordpress navigation

Tags: navigation, rewrite-rules, query-variable

## Setup for getting content

My setup for getting custom content in Network of sites where many sites use the same custom data on the side of worpress generated content.

1. Custom classes to get custom data with the help of wordpress **DB** functions

   - Data is in custom format and in its own table.
   - Basicly the data could be organized as automatically populated custom posts with  custom metadata.
2. Custom **rewrite_rules** to create URL-structure for custom content
3. Custom **templates** to handle the custom data with the help of custom **query_vars**
4. Acivate navigation based on the custom `query_vars`. How to go about doing this? Is there an appropriate wordpress action or filter for the task?

### URL structure for the content

Here is the structure of content explained with URL's:

1. `/vod/` -- frontpage for video archive *VoD*
2. `/vod/series/%series_id%/` -- page for program series listing episodes related to it
3. `/vod/category/%parent_cat%/%sub_cat/` -- page for categories listing all *VoD* series and single programs(like movies and documentaries).
4. `/vod/player/%episode_id%/` -- page for dislpaying single episodes and programs of the *VoD*

### Handling of the custom content

<strike>I can not get my rewrite rule totally exlclusive. What is wrong with my rewrite rules? I admit that regex is really not butter and bread for me.</strike> So the rules seem to be ok.

I get my template redirect to work nicely, but my navigations get activated randomly when the `query_var` value matches post or page. **I want the navigation to match based** on my `query_vars`. Now navigation gets randomly activated as a result of custom `query_vars` matching to navigation.

Here is an example how address gets matched.

```
^vod/series/([0-9]+)/?  
   my_series: 200
(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$    
   pagename: vod/series
   page: /200
```

Here are the `rewrite_rules`, `query_vars` and `template_include`s I've but together:

```
<?php /* Rewrite Rules */
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function my_rewrite_rules() {
   add_rewrite_rule( '^vod/player/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?my_program=$matches[1]', 'top' );
   add_rewrite_rule( '^vod/series/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?my_series=$matches[1]', 'top' );
   add_rewrite_rule( '^vod/category/([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?my_parent_category=$matches[1]&my_category=$matches[2]', 'top' );
   add_rewrite_rule( '^broadcast/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?my_broadcast=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
/* Query Vars */
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_register_query_var' );
function my_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my_program'; //ID for a episode of series or standalone program
    $vars[] = 'my_series'; //ID for a series
    $vars[] = 'my_parent_category'; //ID for parent category
    $vars[] = 'my_category'; //ID for category
    $vars[] = 'my_broadcast'; //ID for broadcast of a program or an episode of a series
    return $vars;
}
    /* Template Include */
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_special_template_include', 1, 1 ); 
function my_special_template_include( $template ){
    global $wp_query; //Load $wp_query object


    $program_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my_program'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['my_program'] : null ); //Check for query var "my_program"
    $series_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my_series'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['my_series'] : null ); //Check for query var "my_series"   
    $bcast_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my_broadcast'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['my_broadcast'] : null );

    $parent_cat_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my_parent_category'] ) ?   $wp_query->query_vars['my_parent_category'] : null );
    //Is it mandatory for $my_category to have an associaton with    $my_parent_category?
    $cat_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my_category'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['my_category'] : null );



    
    if ( $program_page ) { 
        $template = locate_template( array('template-vod-episode'), $load, $require_once );
        return $template;
    } elseif ( $series_page ) {
        $template = locate_template( array('template-vod-series'), $load, $require_once );
        return $template;
    } elseif ( $cat_page || $parent_cat_page ) { 
         $template = locate_template( array('template-vod-category'), $load, $require_once );
       return $template;
    } elseif ( $bcast_page ) {
        $template = locate_template( array('template-vod-broadcast'), $load, $require_once );
        return $template;
    }

    return $template; //Load normal template when $page_value != "true" as a fallback
} ?>
```

Comment: what's the problem exactly? a request can match multiple rules, but the one on top will always win. what are the `my_` query vars, are those WordPress objects? rewrite rules have to result in a successful main query, you can't have all custom vars and no WordPress object- nothing for the loop to output. also- use `locate_template` for your template loading.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and tips. I realised I was not after the right problem. I'm using custom data so those query_vars point to custom objects. Do I need custom endpoints or something else in addition to this?

Comment: The simplest solution is to create a page and point your rewrite rules to that page via `pagename` or `page_id` along with your extra vars.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was trying to move away from that. But I guess it really is the "best" solution in this type of case. I'll post my approach for people to see when the code is done.